# Making a delete button to delete text in the inputtext field

Tags: actionscript-3, button, textinput

I got these four errors when I tried to create a button on the stage that would delete the text I inputted in the inputtext(`ti`). Based on the scripts I have and the errors, what should I write to create the delete button?

> Attempt to delete the fixed property
>   text. Only dynamically defined
>   properties can be deleted. 
>   Access of
>   undefined property delete_btn. 
>   Access
>   of possibly undefined property
>   buttonDown through a reference with
>   static type Class. 
>   Warning: 3600: Thdeclared property text cannot be
>   deleted. To free associated memory,
>   set its value to null.

```
delete_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.buttonDown, deletetxt);
function deletetxt(event:TextEvent):void {
 delete ti.text
 }
ti.border = true
ti.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);
function onInput(event:TextEvent):void {
 if(ti.text.search('a')!=-1) load_image("http://i54.tinypic.com/anom5d.png", "ottefct");
 else if(ti.text.search('b')!=-1) load_image("http://i53.tinypic.com/2dv7dao.png", "rnd");
 else if(ti.text.search('c')!=-1) load_image("http://i51.tinypic.com/m8jp7m.png", "ssd");
}

var loaded_images:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

function load_image(url:String, id_name:String)
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.name = id_name;
    var url_req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadingComplete);
    loader.load(url_req);
}

function onLoadingComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    var img_name:String = evt.currentTarget.loader.name
    var spr_box:Sprite = new Sprite();
    spr_box.addChild(evt.currentTarget.loader);

    spr_box.mouseChildren = false;
    spr_box.doubleClickEnabled = true;

    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, rotate);
    spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK , unrotate);


    spr_box.width = 124;
    spr_box.height = 180;


    this.addChild(spr_box);
    loaded_images[img_name] = spr_box;
}


function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.startDrag()
}

function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.stopDrag()
}

function rotate(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 90
}

function unrotate(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 0
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors!

**Attempt to delete the fixed property text. Only dynamically defined properties can be deleted.**
and
**Warning: 3600: The declared property text cannot be deleted. To free associated memory, set its value to null.**

There is an error when you want to delete the text:

```
function deletetxt(event:TextEvent):void {
    delete ti.text; // <-- Error HERE!
}
```

You should do this instead:

```
function deletetxt(event:MouseEvent):void { // <-- Sorry, didn't see the "TextEvent"
    ti.text = "";
}
```

The `delete` keyword is used to other things (such as delete dictionaries entries)

**Access of undefined property delete_btn**

- Here you doesn't have created the "delete_btn" button (or it has another instance name)

**Access of possibly undefined property buttonDown through a reference with static type Class**

- `MouseEvent.buttonDown` does not exists, maybe you want to use `MouseEvent.CLICK` or `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` instead

Comment: I got this error now.TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::MouseEvent@1edf37c1 to flash.events.TextEvent.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't see the TextEvent, it should be MouseEvent (or just Event)

Answer (score 0):

```
delete_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deletetxt);
function deletetxt(event:Event):void {
 ti.text = "";
 }
```

Unkiwii was right about ti.text = "" but the coercion couldn't convert the Events so I just made it an event:Event

Comment: You should change event:Event to event:MouseEvent